# How to configure AP forwarding

Tags: ip, port-forwarding

[image: Network set up]

I have a device DEV1 which should communicate with device DEV3, however in the middle there is DEV2.

My understanding is that I need to use IP Forwarding in DEV2 and edit route tables on DEV1 and DEV3.

For DEV2 I have enabled IP Forwarding:

-> sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

I can`t set up rest of the things. Could you please help me?

Comment: How is this Ubuntu related?

Comment: From my perspective it is related to all Linux versions. I hope i can ask this question on askubuntu.com

Comment: We don't support all Linux versions here. You can ask at [linux.se].

Comment: Thanks. I will try